# sql find adjacent ranks by attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rank

I am building a leaderboard. Users have points and I want to get the current user and the one that is ranked before and after him.

Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Right now I have to use two querys:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM users 
WHERE points >= [USER.POINTS]
AND id != [USER.ID]
ORDER BY points ASC

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM users 
WHERE points <= [USER.POINTS]
AND id != [USER.ID]
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server, oracle, postgres, etc. Please tag accodingly.

Comment: @Chris Please add version of DB also

Comment: Have you pondered what to do in the event of ties?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use `OUTER APPLY` with an ordered `TOP 1`.

```
SELECT
    U.*,
    P.*,
    N.*
FROM
    Users AS U

    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            PREV.*
        FROM
            Users AS PREV
        WHERE
            PREV.Points <= U.Points AND
            PREV.[User.ID] <> U.[User.ID]
        ORDER BY
            PREV.Points DESC) AS P

    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            NEX.*
        FROM
            Users AS NEX
        WHERE
            NEX.Points >= U.Points AND
            NEX.[User.ID] <> U.[User.ID]
        ORDER BY
            NEX.Points ASC) AS N

WHERE
    U.[USER.ID] = 960 -- Your filtered used ID
```

Another solution with a general ranking (`ROW_NUMBER()`):

```
;WITH UserRankings AS
(
    SELECT
        U.*,
        Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U.Points DESC)
    FROM
        Users AS U
)
SELECT
    U.*,
    PREV.*,
    NEX.*
FROM
    UserRankings AS U
    LEFT JOIN UserRankings AS PREV ON U.Ranking - 1 = PREV.Ranking
    LEFT JOIN UserRankings AS NEX ON U.Ranking + 1 = NEX.Ranking
WHERE
    U.[User.ID] = 960 -- Your filtered User ID
```

Comment: The prev and the next must be with defferent of 1?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `Lead` and `Lag`. Supported by Oracle and Sql server and MySql and probably more.

```
select
    --Pick whatever columns you need from the user.
    tbl.*, 
    Lead.*,
    Lag.*
from
(
select
    *,
    LEAD(ID) OVER (ORDER BY USER.POINTS) LeadId,
    LAG(ID) OVER (ORDER BY USER.POINTS) LagId
from [USER.POINTS]
) tbl
left join core.[User] As Lead on tbl.LeadId = Lead.Id
left join core.[User] As Lag on tbl.LagId = Lag.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lead and lag

```
declare @T table (id int identity primary key, pt int);
insert into @T values (8), (7), (15), (30), (5), (6);

select tt.*
  from ( select t.* 
              , lag(t.ID)  over (order by t.pt, t.id) as prevId
              , lag(t.pt)  over (order by t.pt, t.id) as prevPt
              , lead(t.ID) over (order by t.pt, t.id) as nextId 
              , lead(t.pt) over (order by t.pt, t.id) as nextPt
           from @T t
       ) tt
where tt.ID = 2;

id          pt          prevId      prevPt      nextId      nextPt
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2           7           6           6           1           8
```